# How to use mongoengine in the form of xxx[dbname?]

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

By use pymongo, I can connect to a collection like this:

```
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn.example
collection = db.col
```

and then, I could connect to a database named "example" and collection named "col".

And I could also write code like blow:

```
dbname = 'example'
collectionName = 'col'
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn[dbname]
connection = db[collectionName]
```

This two code block will do the same thing.

Now, I use mongoengine to connect to the MongoDB, and I have a database with  collectionA, I have also a class in a file called 'model.py':

```
class collectionA(Document):
    A=StringField()
    B= StringField()
```

so I could only use:

```
import model
x = model.collectionA.object()
```

to query data.

as I have so many collections, so I'd like to use

```
model[collectionName].object()
```

to query data, but it raise a exception, it seems that mongoengine can not support the form of model[xxx] to connect collections.

So, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried `import appname.model` where appname is your app name and then `model['collectionName'].object()`?
Also, what error do you get you used `model[collectionName].object() `

Comment: appname? This is a python script.

Comment: Mistook it for a Django app because your use of the model as in Django. What error are you getting?

Comment: In fact, this is flask, not Django. And the error is：
    TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing model.py as a module. The square bracket syntax is a "shortcut" to the `getitem` method on an object. [Because everything in python is an object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html), including modules, you are getting a `TypeError` because modules do not have a `getitem` method.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect

import model

collections = dict(inspect.getmembers(model, inspect.isclass))
```

`collections[collectionName].object()` would now work.

FWIW this does not seem very pythonic and the power of mongoengine is that you are mapping the documents to clearly defined classes and this seems to obfuscate that somewhat. It makes it very easy to introduce hard-to-find bugs and also requires extra keystrokes because every class is now referenced as a string.

Comment: thanks a lot and I will have a try later. So as your experience, what is a more pythonic way in this situation?

Comment: The way you propose in your question is fine for me. To save keystrokes you can use `import models as db` and then use `db.CollectionA.objects ()`. One major advantage of this is that if you use an IDE with code inspection like PyCharm then you will get auto-complete options from your model.py